# Do gas-powered plants use Higher Heating Value(s) (HHV) or Lower Heating Value(s) (LHV)?

Tags: energy, electricity, power, combustion

Does anyone know if natural gas power plants, and other utilities for that matter, obtain as much energy as (reasonably) possible from burning methane (or coal, or whatever)?

Where would one find that information, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

In the last 120 years of power plant design and construction, the engineers responsible have striven to wring every last bit of useful heat energy out of every pound of fuel that gets burned in the power plant. Furthermore, since fuel costs almost always go up over time and rarely down, every successive generation of power plant technology is designed to be even more efficient than its predecessors- so as to minimize fuel expenses.

This story, and the current state of the art, is explained in any upper-division mechanical engineering textbook that deals with the thermodynamics of heat engines.